# Populate .Net report viewer control from data table returned from a web servive

Tags: c#, web-services, datatable, reportviewer2008

Thanks in advance for any assistance.  It seems like what i'm trying to do should be very simple, but after literally days of scouring the internet I can't seem to find an answer that pulls it altogether in a simple fashion suitable for an experience .Net developer who is new to the Report Viewer.

Very simply, what I want is an example or step by step demo for the following question:
How do I populate a .Net Report Viewer control using a Data Table returned from a web service?  Within the web service a stored proc is called that returns what eventually ends up in the DataTable that gets sent back to the application.  Would prefer C# answer, but VB is also fine as i am fairly familiar with it.

Related questions to this are:
1. Does the returned DataTable need to have column names and types (does it need to be strongly typed)?
2) If so, do I need to know these column names/types when I am designing the report or is there a way to dynamically create?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a client side report (rdlc), then I would recommend writing a class that holds that data for a row, and binding the datasource (report.LocalReport.DataSource I believe) of the report to a collection of that type.  You can do datasets (which you could put your data table in), but, in my opinion, that mucks up a project and I don't care for it.  I know you're looking for a step-by-step answer, and hopefully someone will give you one, but hopefully my response will get you to change direction a bit.

If you're talking about a server side report (rdl), then you'll need to redo your thinking a bit, as server side reports PULL data, they do not have data pushed onto them.

HTH,
Brian

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Brian.  It is a client side (rdlc) report that I need to create.